# Update and select records in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I have multiple processes accessing the same database table. The table holds "TakenBy" column that is supposed to hold the ID of the taker process.

Entity Framework is my data access layer.

My question would be how can I use my DataContext object so I can retrieve rows from the above table, and have the "TakenBy" column updated ***at the same time***. 
This would allow me to overcome race-condition with the other processes, who also try to get the same records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF will not handle that for you. You must either use stored procedure or you must perform update once you load the record through your application and handle concurrency (either by optimistic way which means to use times tamp or row version column or by [pessimistic way](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/09/entity-framework-and-pessimistic-concurrency/) which means manual SQL query).